# How to train LSTM model for single time series prediction but with multiple dataframes?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

I have to predict whether the shot will be disruptive or non-disruptive. What I have is time-series data of both the types of shots and I want the model to predict using initial period data whether it will be disruptive or not?